# Need Full post back for paging control inside update panel using webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am using Paging control inside UpdatePanel and Paging works fine with no issue using partial postback.

Now i have been asked to change it so that user can move back to page using browser back button suppose i am on new page 1 and then i moved to news page 5 and then i moved to contact page and on contact back if i hit back button then i should show new items of new1 page 5.

I tried to add Trigger control and using `UpdateMode="Conditional"` this didnt not work evry time i  move to next item of the page then if i clict back button it i get document expired error..

```
Document Expired

This document is no longer available.

The requested document is not available in Firefox's cache.

    As a security precaution, Firefox does not automatically re-request sensitive documents.
    Click Try Again to re-request the document from the website.
```

**Below is the code for repeater control**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelvideo" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div class="wrapper-inner">
                    <asp:Repeater ID="rptVideocontrol" runat="server">
                          <ItemTemplate>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 ">
                                <div class="video-item">
                                    <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkvideo" CssClass="playv" NavigateUrl='<%# getURL(Eval("ID"), Eval("YoutubeID")) %>' runat="server">
                                        <div class="video-img-w">
                                            <img src='<%# Path(Eval("Icon"), Eval("ID")) %>' title='<%# Title(Eval("Title")) %>' class="img-responsive img-center" >
                                            <asp:Image ID="imgPlay" CssClass="play-item" AlternateText="Play" ImageUrl="~/images/play0.png" runat="server" />
                                        </div>
                                    </asp:HyperLink>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </div>
                <div class="pager-w">         
                   <uc1:PagerControl ID="PagerControl1" runat="server"  CssClass="pager"  PageMode="LinkButton"   />
                </div>

            </ContentTemplate>
         <%-- <Triggers>
                <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="UpdatePanelvideo" />
            </Triggers>  --%>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

SOme thing similar happens http://www.aspsnippets.com/demos/585/

How can i make paging work with full postback with active Back functionality of browser

and if i move repeater control outside updatepanel

```
          <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
            </ContentTemplate>
          <Triggers>
                <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="PagerControl1" />
            </Triggers>    <%----%>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

then i get page-expired error only in FF but this works in Chrome & IE.. not sure why this is happening..

Comment: Can you just move the PagerControl outside of the UpdatePanel?

Comment: I had even done that also that didn't not work either. I get the same error document expired.

Comment: it is also possible to manage browser history to make back/forward buttons work with UpdatePanels - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488548.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 as one solution, plus there are lots of JavScript or jQuery solutions for this.

Comment: Your pager control must user ASP.NET postback (so http post method). One option might be to rewrite the pager control so that it uses hyperlinks instead - add something like `?page=2` to the URL instead. That would also allow people to bookmark specific pages, and for search engines to index subsequent pages. Otherwise there may be a server side cache setting you can apply to stop the error you are seeing when you don't use the UpdatePanel.

Comment: I moved whole repeater control outside updatePanel `                  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                  <Triggers>
                        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="PagerControl1" />
                    </Triggers>    <%----%>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>` and i get thsi error only in Firefox while it works on Chrome and IE.

Comment: My only suggestion is to research/experiment with server side cache directives to see if you can eliminate that behaviour in Firefox.

Comment: I resolved this issue, By deleted all teh cache in FF broser